# What is the best schedule to learn to do the splits?

Tags: training, gymnastics

I'm trying to develop enought hip flexibility to do the splits as fast as possible, basicaly using Jill Miller's 
"Harmonizing Hips From Inside Out" (http://www.pranamaya.com/miller-hips.html) video. Right know I have extremely low flexibility in muscules and joints. What is best training schedule in my case (or verified "how to do the splits" complete program)? 3/4/5/7 times a week? 1/2 times a day? Or if it's very individual thing - how can I define what is best for me?

Answer (score 1):

I found that lying it splits upside down (feet in air, back on ground) against a wall for 30min each night works. I used to do it while I watched television.

Answer (score 1):

It is an individual thing, but lack of discipline tends to be the problem most people can't overcome. To learn them quickly, you need to balance your schedule between "as often as possible" and "getting lasting pain" (injuries are bad!). That's about an hour or two per day for most beginners. Warming up helps preventing injuries, so don't get lazy on that. The longer you hold the splits, the better and faster the result. Tv, tablets, books are your best friends there.